# bash function to execute a command as argument

Tags: bash, function, arguments

I'm writing a bash script and I have a function that gets 3 arguments, a hostname, a command, and a file, it should excute the command on that hostname and redirect the output to the filename. This is the fucntion:

```
execmd ()
    {
    P_SERV="$1"
    P_CMD="$2"
    P_OUT="$3"

    X_SERV=`hostname`
    if [ "$P_SERV" = "$X_SERV" ] ; then
       $P_CMD >> $P_OUT
    else
       ssh $P_SERV $P_CMD >> $P_OUT
    fi
    }
```

When I execute:

```
execmd venus "cat /proc/meminfo" /tmp/meminfo
```

I get the error

```
cat /proc/meminfo: no such file or directory
```

any idea why its not working? same behavior either if call it with local hostname or remote hostname.

Comment: You're trying to run a command named `cat /proc/meminfo` with no arguments, not `cat` with the argument `/proc/meminfo`.

Comment: If `$P_CMD` isn't quoted, as in the code in the question, it should get word-split when the script runs the command. That should make your example `cat` command work as expected, and indeed the function works for me with `execmd $myhostname "cat /proc/meminfo" output`.

Comment: However, a typo in the file name would show the error from `cat` on the terminal, since stderr isn't redirected, so with `execmd $myhostname "cat /proc/meminfox" output` I get `cat: /proc/meminfox: No such file or directory`. Looking closely at your error message, I think it might come from `cat`, but I suspect it's not copied correctly here: usually the `No` would be with an uppercase `N`.

Comment: Also, the error message from bash would be `bash: catxx: command not found`. Though an older bash (3.1.17 tested) might scramble that if the command name contained a carriage return, but the error is still `command not found`.

Comment: Check whether `/proc/meminfo` actually exists on the host that you are connecting to.  I'm voting to close this as off-topic (typo/problem went away) until such time that the question is clarified about the existence of the file.

Answer (score 0):

SSH executes a remote shell. To get consistent behavior for local execution, execute a local shell.

```
if [ "$P_SERV" = "$X_SERV" ] ; then
   sh -c "$P_CMD" >> "$P_OUT"
else
   ssh "$P_SERV" "$P_CMD" >> "$P_OUT"
fi
```

Don't forget [double quotes around substitutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). For example, without double quotes, if `P_CMD` contains wildcards then they would be expanded locally in `ssh $P_SERV $P_CMD`.